# one modeling in graph and topological sorting

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

we have a Graph `G(|n|, |m|)`. if person `u` knows person `v` there is a `(u, v)` edge. if any person hear a news send it to all friends. (a modeling with graph). we want to send this news to all, using finding minimum number of person that hear our news and share to friends and as a result all of persons get this news. best algorithm is `O(m+n)` using topological sorting.

is there any idea how we can handle this model?

Comment: What are you trying to minimize exactly? The initial number of persons you give the news to originally? The number of sharing-to-friends steps? Little bit of both? Is this the same thing as the [Vertex k-center problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_k-center_problem)? Or are you just trying to find one person per connected component of the graph?

Comment: initial number of persons you give the news to originally, this should be minimized @Stef  inorder to all others hear about our news. I think when this be minimum number of sharing steps is also minimized. anyway the first part is true. at first I think this is K cover vertex but no !

Comment: You seem to have the solution figured out, so what do you expect from an answer? An implementation? Basic data structures?

Comment: @Botje why is differ from Vertex k-center problem and how we use topological sort here ? how can solve? pesudo step.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the k-center problem at all. What makes you think it is?